# Undefined reference to defined function

Tags: c++, g++, undefined-reference

I have a very weird error: I have a pair of .h and .cpp files that contain some functions and constants. When I try to compile it, g++ says "undefined reference" to the function. The function prototype and definition seem to be the same. I have commented everything out except the necessary lines, and g++ still complains about it.

My program is currently (after commenting everything out):

main.cpp

```
#include "a.h"

int main(){
    makehex(10);

    return 0;
}
```

a.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#ifndef __A___

static const std::string b = "01";
static const std::string d = b + "23456789";
static const std::string h = d + "abcdef";

template <typename T> std::string makehex(T value, unsigned int size = 2 * sizeof(T));
#endif
```

a.cpp

```
#include "a.h"

template <typename T> std::string makehex(T value, unsigned int size){
    // Changes a value to its hexadecimal string
    if (!size){
        std::stringstream out;
        out << std::hex << value;
        return out.str();
    }
    std::string out(size, '0');
    while (value && size){
        out[--size] = h[value & 15];
        value >>= 4;
    }
    return out;
}
```

There is only 1 function. I dont see how this could error.

Im compiling with `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp a.cpp` and getting the errors:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `std::string makehex<int>(int, unsigned int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Is it because of the template? If so, how do i fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Template issue causes linker error (C++)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639797/template-issue-causes-linker-error-c)

Comment: You're using a [reserved identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: Bad Karma:  declaring static variables in a header file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common template mistake. The compiler needs to know the definition of the template at compile time: thus, the definition of the template function must be in the header file.

Comment: Or, a specialization of the template must be implemented in the .cpp file.

Comment: @calccrypto What do you think `template <typename T> std::string makehex(T value, unsigned int size)` is?

Comment: @H2CO3 Ha yeah, that is true, that screwed me up the first time i did it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand that templates aren't code themselves but it tells the compiler *how* to generate code that other parts of your program can use. For the compiler to be able to do that automatically it *must have seen the definition* of that template at the point of instantiation.

But in your existing setup, only the *declaration* of `makehex<T>()` is visible in `main.cpp`.  The actual definition of `makehex<T>()` is squirreled away in `a.cpp` which main doesn't know about during compilation (it's in a different translation unit).The easy fix for this is to move implementation of `makehex<T>()` from a.cpp into a.h.

Answer (score 1):

A template function is only emitted when you actually instantiate the template. You are attempting to do this in the main function, using the call `makehex(10)`.

You have included "a.h" in the main.cpp file, so when compiling main.cpp, you have access to the *declaration* of the function. However, the compiler is not able to access the *definition* because it's in a different file (a.cpp) which hasn't been included.

The short-term fix is to `#include "a.cpp"` in main.cpp. However, the long-term fix is not to have .cpp files for template function definitions - put it all in the header (.h) file. (This does NOT apply to ordinary functions/classes etc).